TypeScript Issue: Displaying Error Messages from React Hook Form
I'm working on a registration form using react-hook-form in a React application. My form includes validation for various fields, and I'm trying to display error messages for each field. However, I'm encountering a TypeScript error when attempting to render the error message for the firstName field.
  const Register = () => {
    const { register, watch, handleSubmit,formState:{errors} } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
    })
    
    return (
        <form action="" className="flex flex-col gap-5" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <h2 className="text-3xl">Create an account</h2>
            <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-5">
                <label className="text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold flex-1">
                    First Name
                    <input type="text" className="border border-blue-500 rounded w-full py-1 px-2 font-normal" {...register("firstName", { required: "This field is required" })} />
                    {errors.firstName && (
                     <span className="text-red-500">{errors.firstName.message}</span>
                 )}
                </label>
             <span>
                <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-600 text-white p-2 font-bold hover:bg-blue-500 text-xl">Create Account</button>
            </span>
        </form>

For some reason: {errors.firstName.message} gives me this error:
 Type 'string | FieldError | Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<any>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'FieldError' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    Type 'FieldError' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': children, props, keyts(2322)
index.d.ts(2379, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>'
FieldError | Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<any>>

I have tried googling it as well as reStructuring the program and in some of them it does work, yet I am following a video tutorial and it seems like for the person doing it in the video. It gives no problem whatsoever. Yet for me it throws that error. Since I am still fairly new to TypeScript I appreciate any feedback.
Said video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdBy9-0pER4&t=5496s at 1:56h in case you are curious.

You're missing to tell useForm what type is used for each field. To solve this issue, just simply add a type like this:
type FormValues = {
  firstName: string;
}

const Register = () => {
  const { 
    register, 
    watch, 
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors } 
  } = useForm<FormValues>();

  // ...other code
}

Then typescript should be happy with it.

It did make it happy. Appreciate it!
